# How to easily print nested objects without naming each one

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects, nested-loops

I have an object of objects in which I want to print all the **name** values, how can I do this easily without having to hardcode each one?

```
const myObj = {
  results: {
      one: {
         name: "o", 
         value: 1
      } 
      two: {
         name: "t", 
         value: 2
      }
    }
   ignore: "this"
}
```

I can make it work with `myObj.results.one.name`, but I'd rather be able to do something like a loop where I can swap out the middle value like `results.[1].name` preventing the hard coding of 20 values.

Is there a simple way to do this without hardcoding each one. (The end use is to add them all to an array and use that to populate a table to show name and values)

This [linked](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) answer doesn't answer my question as this is an array of objects so solutions fail, and the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) isn't nested

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @decpk I'm wanting to get an output of just the name values, so like "o, t"

Comment: Note the linked questions don't properly answer what am asking as their structures are different

Comment: Neither links help but I did find a simple solution I can add if the q gets reopened

Comment: If you want `output` in as an array then use `Object.values(myObj.results).map((o) => o.name);` . If you want output in string then use `Object.values(myObj.results)
  .map((o) => o.name)
  .join(", ");`